# Update field in a Column on Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, model, controller, eloquent

I'm trying to update the status on my tickets table to the value : 2.
Once I can create the comment... (is working.. :) ), I wanted to change the status to 2.

This is my ticket model and the following function:

```
 public function addComment($id,$body,$solved)
{    

    $this->find($id)->status = 2;
    $this->save();            


    $this->comments()->create([
        'ticket_id' => $id,
        'body' => $body,
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
}
```

Comment: @AmrAly didn't work :/

Comment: Its unclear to me what you're asking for. It sounds like you want to update the ticket's `status` to 2, but your code seems to be doing that already. Are you getting any sort of error when you try what you have right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your object first then you can Update it:

```
public function addComment($id,$body,$solved)
{    
$ticket = $this->find($id);
$ticket->status = 2;
$ticket->save();            


$ticket->comments()->create([
    'ticket_id' => $id,
    'body' => $body,
    'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: you are welcome If you find my answer useful please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code like this. Maybe this will fix the problem you're having:

```
public function addComment($id,$body,$solved)
{    
    $ticket = Ticket::find($id);
    $ticket->status = 2;
    $ticket->save();            

    $ticket->comments()->create([
        'ticket_id' => $id,
        'body' => $body,
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
}
```